# How to write Junit for clone method catch block

Tags: java, junit, mockito

My respected java developer friends.
i am trying test and  cover the catch block of clone method. I have wasted one week but didn't find any solution to cover catch block. Please help me.

My source code -

```
public class Data implements Cloneable {

    private String A;

    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        try {
            return super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            return new Data();
        }
    }
}
```

My Junit Test Cases -

```
@Test
public void testCloneSucess() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Data data = new Data();
    Data d = (Data) data.clone();
    assertNotNull(d);
}

@Test
public void testCloneFailure() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Data data = new Data();
    doThrow(new CloneNotSupportedException()).when(data.clone());
    assertThrows(CloneNotSupportedException.class, () -> data.clone());
}
```

i have given links for the images, this will give more understanding of question and what i have tried.

1. Source code - [image: source code]
2. junit that i have tried - [image: junits]

Comment: Your source code in image is different to your post, which is the actual one?

Comment: Side note: Writing a test for that method doesn't really make sense

Comment: @samabcde My bad. Thanks for pointing. it was copy paste mistake by me. I have corrected it

Comment: @DanW Mocking `Data.class` defeats the purpose of the test because then you are testing the mock, not `Data.clone()`.

Comment: i am agree with @Code-Apprentice. we cannot mock class under test.

Comment: @AjayKumar Under what condition will `super.clone()` throw `CloneNotSupportedException`? I don't think this will ever happen in real situations, which means the `try...catch` is not really necessary. But then if you remove it, your clone implementation basically is the same as the one in `Object.clone()`.

Comment: One thing to consider, when you return `new Data()` without setting its `A` field, you aren't really cloning anything.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice super.clone() will never throw cloneNotsupportedException as Data class implements cloneable. 
i am trying to cover code coverage detected by sonar tool. i added String A for testing purpose. i have tested positive test cases by setting and reading string values. 

Now i believe i should ignore this catch-block as mentioned by you also it dont make sense to test this catch block because this will not happen in real situations.

Comment: @AjayKumar The best way to increase your code coverage in this case is to delete `Data.clone()`. First of all, your implementation is incorrect or at least has unexpected results. Second of all, 99.99% of the time you should only `implement Cloneable` and let `Object.clone()` do the work without overriding it.

Comment: @AjayKumar When you say "I added String A for testing purposes", do you mean that `A` is only ever used in tests? If so, then I suggest not doing that. Implementation code should only exist to support the purposes of the app.

Comment: @AjayKumar "it dont make sense to test this catch block because this will not happen in real situations" That also means that the `catch` block shouldn't even exist.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A few things before I answer your question:

1. `return new Data();` doesn't actually clone anything because the `A` field in returned the object is not guaranteed to be the same as `this.A`. You can fix this by doing something like

   ```
   Data other = new Data();
   other.A = this.A
   return other;
   ```
2. But now your custom implementation has the exact same behavior as `Object.clone()`, so there is no reason for it. Generally, you only need to `implement Cloneable`. You don't need to override `clone()` unless you have some very special processing needed that doesn't happen with the bitwise clone which `Object` already gives us.

With that said, to test the path that throws an exception, you need to create a condition where something in the `try` block throws the specific exception you want to test. In this case, the only choice is to cause `super.clone()` to throw `CloneNotSupportedException`. That means you have to mock `Object.clone` and cause it to throw the exception.

Additionally, you don't want to `assertThrows(CloneNotSupportedException.class, () -> data.clone());` because `Data.clone()` never throws this exception. Instead, you need an assertion that is based on the expected behavior in the `catch` block. In this case, that something is returned.

Comment: i tried to mock object.clone(). clone method protected so it is not visible from my test class. i tried to use reflection to access it but it didnt help.